# image does not display in ipython

Tags: ipython

The image does not load if it is part of a while loop. For e.g. the following works as expected:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='someimage.jpg')
```

But this does not work:

```
while True:
    Image(filename='someimage.jpg')
    break
```

update:

How do I display several images from a list?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in a loop ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not loaded? I've tried and it works in both cases for me, but with the loop the image is not shown (not the last evaluated expression); I must save it in a variable, and then I can display it.

Comment: Because I want to display several images from a list. I tried print Image(filename='xyz') but it still does not display it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works fine here:

```
from IPython.display import display, Image

path1 = "/some/path/to/image1.png"
path2 = "/some/path/to/image2.png"

for path in path1, path2:
    img = Image(path)
    display(img)
```

Comment: Doesn't display anything from me, just returns: >>> display(image)
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
In :

Comment: @alper, for me it still works with the latest version of ipython/jupyter. Hard to tell why it does not work for you.

Comment: Does this need to be run inside of jupyter? That documentation is kind of a jumble. Can't I just run this with python and see the result?

Comment: @alper, this code is written for ipython/jupyter notebook. It may or may not work in an ipython interpreter - although I doubt that it will be of any use in an interpreter. It will certainly not work in a pure python shell.

Comment: The documentation around this is really weird. I got it to run by copy pasting it line by line into a notebook but that seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Maybe it's a version issue, but I've been working on the Udacity TensorFlow notebooks with the provided Docker image, and Image in a loop does not work.  It will work outside of the loop, inside the loop it displays nothing.

Comment: It does not from the python cell.  You will need to use iptyhon notebook.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I have exactly the same problem as apler details above.  I am going thru a detailed example, where IPython is used to create an image. After several attempts, I have successfully displayed a .jpg image from a file, and **confirmed Mac OSX Yosemite can use Python+PIL** to display an image.

I had to uninstall PIL, and use Pillow instead, in order for the libjpeg library to be recognized correctly. The Python code *creates* an image - but it will not *display* the image.

I try to create the image with:

```
f = BytesIO()
PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, 'jpeg')
clear_output(wait = True)
display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
```

What I see when I run the little program in Python is:

```
<IPython.core.display.Image object> 
In :
```

This In : looks to be an IPython prompt.

It appears that the code example I am working through is specifically designed to use IPython *Notebook* which is **not** the same as IPython, or interactive Python.

To use the code above, which is from the Google TensorFlow tutorial, one needs to configure an "IPython Notebook Server" and run something called "Jupyter".  The documentation for Jupyter stuff is at:
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The point apler makes is good.  We should just be able to use plain Python to create a .jpg file, and display it on a Mac running OSX.  I've pulled some code togther to show how to do this.  It creates a .jpg image, writes it out to a file, and then displays it using Pillow version of PIL.  (Note: I had to use pip to uninstall original PIL, then pip install Pillow, and I picked up the "libjpeg" library as a .dmg file from the Ethan.Tira-Thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html site).  You also need numpy and scipy.misc modules.

```
#
# --- Make+Show immediately a simulated Moire pattern as a .jpg file
#
# --- start Python and import this file with: import MakeShowMoire
# --- or use: execfile ("MakeShowMoire.py")
#
# --- import modules we need 
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
#
# --- Ok, lets go..
width = 1020
height = 710
channels = 3
#
img = np.zeros((height, width, channels), dtype=np.uint8)
xx, yy = np.mgrid[:height, :width]
circle = (xx - 100) ** 2 + (yy - 100) ** 2
for y in range(img.shape[0]):
    for x in range(img.shape[1]):
        r, g, b = circle[y][x], circle[y][x], circle[y][x]
        img[y] [x] [0] = r
        img[y] [x] [1] = g
        img[y] [x] [2] = b

#
# --- now, we have made the image, lets save it
scipy.misc.imsave("testimg.jpg", img)
#
# --- Since we have saved it, we should be able to display it
image = Image.open("testimg.jpg")
image.show()
```

Save this file as MakeShowMoire.py.  To run this, start a terminal session, and run Python. I am using Python 2.7.10 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang 600.0.39)] on darwin, and  Mac OSX is 10.10.5 Yosemite.  When Python runs, just enter:

```
>>> execfile ("MakeShowMoire.py")
```

And the example should display on your Mac, in a window called "tmpblahblah.BMP", which will be pitched when you close the window, but your testimg.jpg is retained, of course.
I was using "import MakeShowMoire" at Python prompt to run the file, but the namespace does not map to the interactive Python session.  If you use the execfile function, you can re-display the file contents with image.show() again.  Hope this is useful.

Comment: I did the following with the original tensorflow example.
`#display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))`
`scipy.misc.imsave("testimg.jpg", a)`
`image = PIL.Image.open("testimg.jpg")`
`image.show()`

Answer (score 2):

When working in IPython notebooks, the interpreter will give a response when typed as a separate command.

So for example:

```
>>>>a = 5
>>>>a
5
```

But if we were to do the same thing in a function or loop, we would not get the response.

So if you want to display images from within a loop/function, you will have to use the display function (IPython.display.display)

```
from IPython.display import display, Image

for image_path in images:  # images is a list of paths
    display(Image(image_path))
```

So the Image function is returning an image. When in the interpreter, it will get displayed, but otherwise it will not. 
To ensure that it is displayed, we use the display function.

This is similar to the print command. When in the interpreter, it is not necessary to use the print command to view variables, whereas while running a program it is.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the chosen answer, and just about everything else under the sun, but no matter what I tried, it would only display the last photo.  I was finally able to get it working with matplotlib.

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def display_photo(path):
    print("File: {}".format(path))
    img = mpimg.imread(path)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

for path in glob.iglob('my_photos/*'):
    display_photo(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Import Image from IPython]

[image: Pass url to download Image]

Note: The image displays in a different window - image viewer. If using QtConsole, one could set the display to inline using `%matplotlib inline`

Hope this helps.

Comment: The data is not held by the console so it has nothing to shown not unless the console is told to retain the data by setting embed to true. That gives it a resource to a handle in building or showing the image.

Comment: Please, **never ever** post code as a picture. That's an absolute no go on Stack Overflow. Please remove that, this post requires some edit. If you think you need to include more information, that's not meant to be part of the comment section, but rather add it to your original answer.

Answer (score -1):

Imports and that function can be rewritten as below. It perfectly opens windows photo viewer with the result fractal image

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from IPython.display import display


def DisplayFractal(a, fmt='jpeg'):
    a_cyclic = (6.28*a/20.0).reshape(list(a.shape)+[1])
    img = np.concatenate([10+20*np.cos(a_cyclic),
                          30+50*np.sin(a_cyclic),
                          155-80*np.cos(a_cyclic)], 2)
    img[a==a.max()] = 0
    a = img
    a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
    Image.fromarray(a).show()
```