# IPython display only outputs to console with ST3

Tags: python

Good morning SO,

**Setup :**

Windows 7 (I know)

Sublime Text 3

Python 3.6

**My problem :**

I have some 28x28 images in a file, say one of them is at the relative path 'MyDir/myimage.png'

I'm trying to display the example image using the *display* module in the package *IPython*

```
from IPython.display import display,Image

img=Image(filename='MyDir/myimage.png')

display(img)
```

The problem is that instead of outputing the image in a figure, it only outputs the type of the object img in the console (display displays only in console).

**Output :**

```
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `print type(img)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPython (interactive python) won't work as expected in the console.

But in jupyter notebook, for instance, all goes well:

[image]

There's also [qtconsole](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole) which sounds like it's just a more console-like jupyter notebook. I haven't checked it out, since between vscode and jupyter notebook, I've been fine thus far.

To learn more, you could search for comparisons between tools like jupyter and qt. And also take a look at the IPython docs. But if you just want the darn thing to show you an image, you could run your python script in jupyter or the like. Or use `PIL` as this [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567537/3144603) mentions.

Also, you could use `matplotlib.pyplot` to show images instead (this works in console *and* in jupyter):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, imshow, axis, show
from matplotlib.image import imread
import numpy as np
import os

imageDirectory = "c:\\some\\directory\\of\\images"
list_of_files = np.array(os.listdir(imageDirectory))[0:20] # just show the first 20 images
fig = figure()
number_of_files = len(list_of_files)
for i in range(number_of_files):
    a=fig.add_subplot(1,number_of_files,i+1)
    image = imread(os.path.join(imageDirectory, list_of_files[i]))
    imshow(image,cmap='Greys_r')
    axis('off')

show()
```