# cannot save image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I can make an image and save it to a file this way:

```
Img1 = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (512,512))
display(newImg1)
Img1.save("img1.jpg","JPEG")
```

but this image wont save

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image

def makePic(a, fmt='jpeg'):
    a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
    f = StringIO()
    result=PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    result=(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
    return result


Img2 = np.float32(PIL.Image.new('RGB', (512,512)))
imag=makePic(Img2)
display(imag)
imag.save("img1.jpg","JPG")

----> 4 imag.save("img1.jpg","JPG")

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'save'
```

display(imag) shows the picture fine but python thinks it's not an image. why?

Comment: What is `display`?

Comment: How do you manage to use `StringIO` without `import`?

Comment: What's your function `makePic` returning is probably different class `Image` than you expect. Everywhere else you reference the `Image` class as `PIL.Image`, only on the line `result=(Image(data=f.getvalue()))` you don't, why?

Comment: Use a debugger or `ipython` so you can inspect what variables actually contain.

Comment: so when  I do: print (type(Img1)

Comment: so when  I do: print (type(Img1) , I get <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
but when I do:  print type(imag), I get <class 'IPython.core.display.Image'> . so Dawid is correct. Furthermore, if I change 'result' in the makePic def so that
result=(PIL. Image(data=f.getvalue())) then I get the error that:              <ipython-input-123-174d21360286> in makePic(a, fmt)
      8     f = StringIO()
      9     PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
---> 10     result=(PIL. Image(data=f.getvalue()))
     11     return (result)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: display is from the IPython.display class. Properly I should import it like so: from IPython.display import display, Image

Answer (score 0):

This thread gave me clue:
[image does not display in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237210/image-does-not-display-in-ipython)

unfortunately 'scipy.misc.imsave' is now deprecated and I have to use imageio

But then i could not simply

```
pip install imageio
```

It gave me some mumbo jumbo about using sudo and the -H flag. Well I did that and indeed when I started python I could do this

```
>>>import imageio
>>>
```

but when I start the jupyter-notebook, the notebook was stupid and said 'no module named imageio'

So then I tried to install it again and got this

```
$pip install imageio
Requirement already satisfied: imageio in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from imageio) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from imageio) (1.13.3)
```

How did it end up in the python3 dir ? So I decided to to try this

```
$python -m pip install imageio --user
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: imageio in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imageio) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imageio) (1.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imageio) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imageio) (5.4.1)
```

Why do I want to keep using python 2.7? Well, because I have these rather long python programs that I dont feel like troubleshooting to get them to work in python3. Anyway, now when I open jupyter-notebook, I can do this

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import imageio
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display

img2 = np.float32(PIL.Image.new('RGB', (256,512)))
imageio.imwrite('test.jpg', img2[:, :, 0])
```

and it saves a proper jpg to disk. But if I try to view it like so

```
display(img2)
```

obviously, I just get the numpy array. So to display it, I have to convert the array with the makePic def like so:

```
img2 = np.float32(PIL.Image.new('RGB', (125,512)))
imageio.imwrite('test.jpg', img2[:, :, 0])
#display(img2)
image=makePic(img2)
display(image)
```

Interestingly, the imageio.imwrite call just writes the numpy array to disk but when I go to the file and open it in ubuntu, obviously, the image viewer does the numpy array to image conversion.